# Display selective data in UITableView from an array

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I Have an NSMutableArray which is being displayed as

```
 (
          13002,
          My Drive,
          13006,
          Testing1,
          13007,
          Testing123    
 )
```

In my NSLog

I want to populate my UITableView with just the names (My Drive, Testing1 & Testing123) and want to use the ID's as the subtitle.

Comment: try my answer you will be succeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use cell for row at indexpath method and number of rows method as below

```
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
        return array.count/2;
 }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      int row = [indexPath row]*2;

      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
              cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
              cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
              cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
     }    

     cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:row+1];
     cell.detailTextLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:row];

     return cell;
}
```

your problem will solve...

Comment: Some more help required. I need to pass this ID to another file where it is used to call a sublist.

Comment: then first find row same as above in tableview didselect row at indexpath method and pass [array objectatindex:row] in next viewcontroller

Comment: check the question i posted here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613499/passing-data-to-another-tableview

Answer (score 0):

```
NSmutableArray *element; //contains your array

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    element = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = element;


    element = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row +1 ];
    cell.subtitle.text = element;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application, you might want to consider using a NSMutableDictionary instead of the array. This way, your data model will accurately represent the fact that those names are mapped to ids. You can use

```
NSArray *arrayOf Keys = [theDictionary allKeys];
```

to get an array of the keys in your dictionary, then do something like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [theDictionary objectForKey:[arrayOfKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.detailtextLabel.text = [arrayOfKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider using the free Sensible TableView framework. You would just pass the array to the framework and it will automatically display it in the table view.